# Laravel One to One, inverse relationship

Tags: laravel-4, one-to-one

I'm working with tables with one-to-one relationship. I have `Users` and `Vendedores`. 
**User Model**

```
public function vendedor(){
  return $this->hasOne('Vendedor', 'users_id');
}
```

**Vendedor Model**

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

I know I can do this to get any attribute form `Vendedor`

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->name; 
$user->lastname;
...
$user->vendedor->carnet;
```

But how can I do the inverse, having an id from `Vendedores` like this:

```
$vendedor = Vendedor::find($id);
$nombre = $vendedor->user->name;
```

Is it possible? I always get this error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Comment: I believe you have to specify the fk as well in the user method.

Comment: Do you mean this `$this->belongsTo('User', 'users_id')` ?

Comment: Yes. Have you tested?

Comment: That was it! Thank you, please answer so I can pick you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to specify the fk as well in the `user` method, such as:

```
$this->belongsTo('User', 'users_id')
```